# XAML DataContext DesignInstance with nested types

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to specify a nested type for d:DesignInstance in XAML? And if so, how?

If I have the following class structure:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class OuterClass
    {
        public class InnerClass
        {
             public string SomeData {get;set;}
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the `InnerClass` type as a DesignInstance? The following doesn't work:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" 
    ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:OuterClass.InnerClass}"
 >
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing `.` to `+`. Something like:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" 
    ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:OuterClass+InnerClass}">
```

Comment: Genius! How I never thought of that is beyond me. Thanks!

Comment: What a pitty that this does not work for WPF...